# Left join table until no parent and table structure

Tags: mysql

By referring table in the link, I have table category and another table name "package" to store category id.
http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

```
Category
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

Is there anyway I can left join until there is no parent left without knowing how many times I have to join?

And second question, my table "package" is only storing the last/smallest category id, for example in the table is "7 - FLASH", is that a good practices to only store the last/smallest category id and refer it back by joining the table? Will this action making the database heavy by query it back every time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately no, till now mysql does not support these kind of hierarchical query http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Hello @AbhikChakraborty so I have to use php to query it back every time to get the main parent id? Will it heavy the database by query so many times?

Comment: You don't have to query your database multiple times. You can just fetch all the rows, and then loop through it, and build tree structure as needed. As MySQL has no biult-in support fur such a functionality - consider switching to other RDBMS. eg. PostgreSQL can do it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Hello murison, is a company project, so I can't switch as it was currently using MySQL. And can anyone answer me regarding the second question?

Comment: @Info perhaps you can write a recursive function to do the job and yes you need to send multiple queries.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thank you very much. What about the second question?

Comment: For hundreds or even thousand of records it does not matter. And I assume you will not have millions of category.

Comment: Maybe it will, cause I merged item and category together, what is your suggestion to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do such queries in MySQL.

If you need to keep this database structure, then the fastest approach is likely to select the relevant data from the table and then process the data client-side into the approach array/join.

The above may not work well if you cannot sufficiently narrow down the number of rows to SELECT out, in which case, recursively running multiple queries may be faster.  On your second query, the best approach is to do something like WHERE id IN (list_of_parent_values) rather than 1 query per parent.

Lastly if you can change your data structure, there is a way of using special tree column values to efficiently select all of the nodes out with a single SQL query.  Some more work is required to insert and re-organise the tree however.
There are a number of slightly differing implementations of this, see here for one such discussion:
http://web.archive.org/web/20110606032941/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

awesome_nested_set is also a ruby implementation of this pattern:
https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

Comment: Just looked Nested Set Model, but I afraid it was not suitable for me as my data will become bigger, it was too huge to update thousand of data if my data reach that limit or beyond that, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: the nested set is basically optimising for reads, instead of writes.  depends on your access pattern.